# Cacti - Interpreting values for Network statistics

Tags: centos, cacti, percona, template

I've downloaded and installed the Percona Linux template. I noticed the values for tx-drop had values of 'm' and 'u' and don't quite understand why I'm getting values of micro and milli.

I was expecting reading to simply be the number of packet dropped at that point of time but it doesn't appear so.

So I'm interpreting it as follows:
* A defined time period divided by the number of dropped packets. eg. 12.5m would mean 80 packets dropped within a second. 150u would mean 6666.67 packets dropped within a second (1/150u)

Is this interpretation of the reading correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  The values displayed on the graph will be a rate, i.e. drops/second.  Cacti collects a counter value every X minutes (5 by default), which increases monotonically.  RRD will then graph counter-type values as a rate, as you have seen.